# adjustText incorrectly positions annotations when x and y values greater than 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

We're using matplotlib and adjustText to plot XY coordinates and pass a list of labels to specific points in the plot and prevent the labels from overlapping one another.

However, I noticed that applying adjust_text to XY values that are greater than 1 causes the labels to be displayed incorrectly. Here's a sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
y = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('Peaks')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

annotations = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    annotations.append(plt.text(x[i], y[i], "Label" + str(i)))
```

Running this, I get the following:

[image: Plot without adjustText]

Once I add this:

```
adjust_text(annotations,arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color='k', lw=0.5))
```

I get this image:

[image: Plot with adjustText]

If I change my x and y values to:

```
x = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
y = [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
```

with the adjust_text line, I get this image:

[image: Plot with small values and adjustText]

So it seems like it's working for relatively small values. Is there a parameter that I'm missing?

This is on Python 3.9, matplotlib 3.8.2, adjustText 0.8. This was also happening with matplotlib 3.7.1, I just checked out of curiosity.

Update: I tried it on Python 3.11 based on a comment and I got the same results.

Comment: I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaZHR.png. Python 3.10, matplotlib 3.8.1, adjustText 0.8.

Comment: @BigBen could it be the Python version?

Comment: Updated to Python 3.11 and I got the same results.